# Typescript: a Map of keys from a different enums throws an error

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an error when I try to create a map that contains keys from the different enums. Despite the fact that both enums contains string values.
While the map keys are from the same enum there is no error.

```typescript
export enum FirstName {
  Alex = 'alex',
  Bob = 'bob'
}
 
export enum Lastname {
  Smith = 'smith',
  Abrams = 'abrams'
} 

// This is okay!
const map1: ReadonlyMap<string, any> = new Map([
  [FirstName.Alex, 'foo'],
  [FirstName.Bob, 'bar']
]);

// This is also okay!
const map2: ReadonlyMap<string, any> = new Map([
  [Lastname.Smith, 'foo'],
  [Lastname.Abrams, 'bar']
]);

// This code throws an error!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
const map3: ReadonlyMap<string, any> = new Map([
  [FirstName.Alex, 'foo'],
  [Lastname.Smith, 'bar']
]);
```

JavaScript-wise this code is fine, but TS throw the following error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(iterable: Iterable<readonly [FirstName, string]>): Map<FirstName, string>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '([FirstName.Alex, string] | [Lastname.Smith, string])[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Iterable<readonly [FirstName, string]>'.
      The types returned by '[Symbol.iterator]().next(...)' are incompatible between these types.
        Type 'IteratorResult<[FirstName.Alex, string] | [Lastname.Smith, string], any>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorResult<readonly [FirstName, string], any>'.
          Type 'IteratorYieldResult<[FirstName.Alex, string] | [Lastname.Smith, string]>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorResult<readonly [FirstName, string], any>'.
            Type 'IteratorYieldResult<[FirstName.Alex, string] | [Lastname.Smith, string]>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorYieldResult<readonly [FirstName, string]>'.
              Type '[FirstName.Alex, string] | [Lastname.Smith, string]' is not assignable to type 'readonly [FirstName, string]'.
                Type '[Lastname.Smith, string]' is not assignable to type 'readonly [FirstName, string]'.
                  Type at position 0 in source is not compatible with type at position 0 in target.
                    Type 'Lastname.Smith' is not assignable to type 'FirstName'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(entries?: readonly (readonly [FirstName, string])[] | null | undefined): Map<FirstName, string>', gave the following error.
    Type 'Lastname.Smith' is not assignable to type 'FirstName'.
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwGIEsoGcYByAhqsHAN4BQcNcAggDahwC8cA5EUyOwDTW0AQhABGrDiNHtKAXwE1KoSLAQp0AGSL5EJMlVpwAyqiwwAFuPa4T5vvPoioJXJaKPn0mXEqUA9L7gAFTMsF1C4CABrIgBPAEJKAGMIRHw4ZMQAE1MsFNwARgAuOAAlYCJMlIYYgFkiMAAefCgsRABzXjgiRBiAPnFEYAB3ODqwAAoAbXtJ7DxCXQA6RlBO9gAzCAh2AF1+A1mcfGJSReERNZEiKF3KHYBKAG4ffyCQsJcuXAgI6PikvLwDLZGC5VIAJmKZQqVVq9SaMBa7U63T6A2Go3qUxmmm0S2MpjMa022z2OK0MB0pzo7lQuEu11uD2efgCwXCyUyZHMUAgQ0+iAQUF5UDiYvFEslCQyaWBOTyAGYoeVKohqmMEUiOl0ev02IMRmNsQc5sclisQMStrt9rRJrjKfibESJIydncnkA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that TypeScript can't infer the generic type arguments for the `Map` (on the right-hand side of the `=`) because the key types don't overlap (since TypeScript provides type safety for string enums, even though they're strings at runtime). If you're explicit about the types in the `Map` so TypeScript doesn't have to infer, it works:

```typescript
// This code works now too
const conditions3: ReadonlyMap<string, any> = new Map<string, any>([
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    [FirstName.Alex, 'foo'],
    [Lastname.Smith, 'bar']
]);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwGIEsoGcYByAhqsHAN4BQcNcAggDahwC8cA5EUyOwDTW0AQhABGrDiNHtKAXwE1KoSLAQp0AGSL5EJMlVpwAyqiwwAFuPa4T5vvPoioJXJaKPn0mXEqUA9L7gAFTMsF1C4CABrIgBPAEJKAGMIRHw4ZMQAE1MsFNwARgAuOAAlYCJMlIYYgFkiMAAefCgsRABzXjgiRBiAPnFEYAB3ODqwAAoAbXtJ7DxCXQA6RlBO9gAzCAh2AF1+A1mcfGJSReERNZEiKF3KHYBKAG4ffyCQsJcuXAgI6PikvLwDLZGC5VIAJmKZQqVVq9SaMBa7U63T6A2Go3qUxmmm0S2MpjMa022z2OK0MB0pzo7lQuEu11uD2efgCwXCyUyZCG0EiLkQEBGMC2ANSQJSILBuAAzFDypVENUxgikR0uj1+mxBiNlc1WmrUb1sQc5sclisQMStrt9rRJrjKfibESJIydncnkA)

Comment: Works. Well, thank you for the solution, and especially for the explanation.

Comment: @SergeiPanfilov - Glad to help! It led me to asking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67003094/can-you-make-ts-infer-variable-generic-type-arguments-from-those-on-the-value)...