# Can you make TS infer a variable's generic type arguments from those on the value being assigned?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67002537/typescript-a-map-of-keys-from-a-different-enums-throws-an-error) the solution was to specify type arguments on the `Map` constructor, like this:

```typescript
const conditions3: ReadonlyMap<string, any> = new Map<string, any>([
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    [FirstName.Alex, 'foo'],
    [Lastname.Smith, 'bar']
]);
```

Note that the OP wanted to give `conditions3` the type `ReadonlyMap<string, any>`, not just a `Map<string, any>`; otherwise we could have just removed the type annotation from `conditions3` entirely.

Unfortunately, that means repeating the type arguments on both `ReadonlyMap` and `Map`.

In the **general** case, is there a way to tell TypeScript to infer the type arguments for the variable/const's type (`ReadonlyMap` in this example) from the type arguments on the value being assigned (`Map` in this example)? I don't mean solutions to this specific case (I think I'd probably have a function, perhaps one that literally provided a read-only map, at least in development builds), but a general infer-from-the-target solution?

My various naive approaches don't work (the first two inspired by Java's `<>`):

```typescript
const conditions3: ReadonlyMap<> = new Map<string, any>([
//                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^−−−−− Generic type 'ReadonlyMap<K, V>' requires
//                                    2 type argument(s).(2314)
    [FirstName.Alex, 'foo'],
    [Lastname.Smith, 'bar']
]);
```

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwGIEsoGcYByAhqsHAN4BQcNcAggDahwC8cA5EUyOwDTW0AQhABGrDiNHtKAXwE1KoSLAQp0AGSL5EJMlVpwAyqiwwAFuPa4T5vvPoioJXJaKPn0mXEqUA9L7gAFSgATyxEAHM4GAg4IgA3CCwAE2iQsDIiKAi0JBgXCEQ4AAMAJWAiZMKGEIBZIjBigDoWygBjQvw4DsRk0yxOgGYALjhyyuq6hoAeAD5xRGAAdzh6sGn8KHCI3jjEENmACgBte2PsPEJdJsZQXfYAMwgIdgBdfgNjzW1r41Mze4iLJvSivACUAG4gA)

```typescript
const conditions3: ReadonlyMap<string, any> = new Map<>([
// Same error with no matching overloads the OP had −^^
    [FirstName.Alex, 'foo'],
    [Lastname.Smith, 'bar']
]);
```

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwGIEsoGcYByAhqsHAN4BQcNcAggDahwC8cA5EUyOwDTW0AQhABGrDiNHtKAXwE1KoSLAQp0AGSL5EJMlVpwAyqiwwAFuPa4T5vvPoioJXJaKPn0mXEqUA9L7gAFSgATyxEAHM4GAg4IgA3CCwAE2iQsDIiKAi0JBgXCEQ4AAMAJWAiZMKGEIBZIjBigDoWygBjQvw4DsRk0yxOgGYALjhyyuq6hoAefChwiN44xBCAPnFEYAB3OHqwadWACgBte2PsPEJdJsZQJfYAMwgIdgBdfgNjzW1r41Mze4iLJvSivACUAG4gA)

```typescript
const conditions3: ReadonlyMap = new Map<string, any>([
//                 ^^^^^^^^^^^−−−−− Generic type 'ReadonlyMap<K, V>' requires
//                                  2 type argument(s).(2314)
    [FirstName.Alex, 'foo'],
    [Lastname.Smith, 'bar']
]);
```

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwGIEsoGcYByAhqsHAN4BQcNcAggDahwC8cA5EUyOwDTW0AQhABGrDiNHtKAXwE1KoSLAQp0AGSL5EJMlVpwAyqiwwAFuPa4T5vvPoioJXJaKPn0mXEqUA9L7gAFSgATyxEAHM4GAg4IgA3CCwAE2iQsDIiKAi0JBgXCEQ4AAMAJWAiZMKGEIBZIjBigDoWygBjQvw4DsRk0yxOgGYALjhyyuq6hvFEYAB3OHqwAB58KHCI3jjEEIA+AAoAbXtD7DxCXSbGUC32ADMICHYAXX4DQ81tS+NTM1uRLIvSjPACUAG4gA)

Is the repetition avoidable in the general case?

Here's the setup code (so it's in the question, not just linked):

```typescript
export enum FirstName {
    Alex = 'alex',
    Bob = 'bob'
}
    
export enum Lastname {
    Smith = 'smith',
    Abrams = 'abrams'
}
```

Comment: I think this is the syntax and there is no way around it. Java has special syntax that allows this to be done, whereas TS is a bit more like C# in this regard.

Comment: @theMayer - Yeah, that's basically the question: Is there syntax for this that I'm missing? :-) I *suspect* not, but TypeScript is vast and my knowledge of it...not vast. And despite recent concerted efforts, the more recent aspects of it remain underdocumented. So I'm hopeful there's something I've missed. I mean, [`function makeReadonly<Key, Value>(map: Map<Key, Value>): ReadonlyMap<Key, Value> { return map; }`](https://tsplay.dev/mbk3oW) isn't awful, it's just...I wonder if there's some more generic (!) way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no syntax for partial inference in variables unfortunately.

The only work around would be to use a function as you mention in the comments:

```
function roMap<Key, Value>(map: Map<Key, Value>): ReadonlyMap<Key, Value> { return map; } 

const conditions3 = roMap(new Map<string, any>([
    [FirstName.Alex, 'foo'],
    [Lastname.Smith, 'bar']
]));
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwGIEsoGcYByAhqsHAN4BQcNcAggDahwC8cA5EUyOwDTW0AQhABGrDiNHtKAXwE1KoSLAQp0AGSL5EJMlVpwAyqiwwAFuPa4T5vvPoioJXJaKPn0uZQBmyRAGMYLAhEOCgIAFkiMAAeAGlgAE9eOAA1LmRgAD4AClRogC44KNiE5LSM7IBKIoAlYCIAExCGRJL4pJT0hkysijDgGGQoUPywAG44GThKSn8Q-Dh5xEbTYMRcAGZxcJKcxGAAd2LomPwoLEQAcxSiRETcgG17R+w8Ql0AOkZQFPZvCAQdgAXX4Bkemm0X2MpjMfxERCgIMowKqVXGQA)

Comment: Just recently, jcalz used a no-op function like the above to solve [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66989064/how-to-define-a-type-from-an-existing-type-but-with-optional-keys-not-with-part), so this approach comes up from time to time to solve type problems.  Do you know if there's been talk of adding some new construct to TypeScript that does exactly what these do-nothing functions do from a types perspective, but gets entirely removed from the emitted JavaScript?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I don't know of any such plans.. I think to do it right, it would end up as complex as the type parameter list, coupled with a single parameter. That would be pretty verbose syntax for a very specialized use case .. not sure it would be worth it. I mean somethinf like `Map<?, ?>` seems simple enough, but what if those two `?` need further constraints, what of they can be any type, but there is a relation between them. These are expessable in a type parameter list, it would be great to express them in a partially inferred variable type too .. which would lead to the complexities

Comment: Thanks! You'd know better than I, it's just that using these do-nothing functions seems a bit silly when all we're doing with them is applying/narrowing/etc. types... :-)